# How to join two tables if there is no relation between id and idfk

Tags: sql

I've two tables `table1` and `table2`. Those tables do not have any relationship between them. I mean there is no `t1.id = t2.idfk`. I need to take one column from `table2` and put it into select where are many rows from `table1`. There is a column `idfk` which is an `idfk` in `table1` and `table2`. Is it okay to use the following SQL query?

```
select t1.id, t2.name
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.addressidfk = t2.addressidfk
and t1.addressidfk = 3003`
```

Comment: You say *those tables do not have relationship between them* so how do you use `where t1.addressidfk = t2.addressidfk`?

Comment: @forpas sorry, this is only field is this okay what I wrote above or not?

Comment: This is an archaic join syntax, not used any more but it is syntactically correct.

Comment: If those 2 tables both have a foreign key to the same 3th table, they yeah, `t1.addressidfk = t2.addressidfk` would seem legit.  But one could drag that 3th table in the query.

Comment: @forpas when I wouldn't do `t1.addressidfk = t2.addressidfk` and only would write `t1.addressidfk = 3003` I am getting wrong rows.

Comment: We can only guess here. If both tables are related to a third table you can join them, but this is often a bad idea. Let's say one table is persons, the other is pets. If there are four persons and three pets in a family, you'd get 4 x 3 = 12 result rows for the address, because you combine each person with each pet in this address. The question is: what is it that you want to achieve with your join?

Comment: I can't tell what is right or what is wrong in this case. Post sample data and expected results and clarify.

Comment: Your question does not makes much sense, because you say the tables do not have any relationship between them but you are using `t1.addressidfk = t2.addressidfk`

Maybe you don't have a Foreign Key but surelly both table share at least one piece of information that can be used to merge data.

Comment: In this case the tables has a relationship but this relation os not direct. Is like a indirect relationship.. cause booth has relationship to a same table.. i guess is nothing wrong with joining using their foreign keys to same table. But seems more intuitive start from the Common related table and Join your two tables.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a column idfk which is an idfk in table1 and table2

If by this you mean that both tables contain a column that is a foreign key referencing the same column in another table, then you can do the join, just use proper syntax for the join:

```
select t1.id, t2.name 
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 
on t1.idfk = t2.idfk 
where t1.addressidfk = 3003
```